# Copying a file from Microsoft Windows 10 to Debian Linux version 9.5

Tags: debian, windows, file-transfer

I have just read a portion of the article entitled: "*How to upload a file from Windows to Linux?*" In that article, there was a link to WinSCP.  I downloaded that program, but I need to know if it is possible to transfer a file from Microsoft Windows 10 ( `c:/` ) to my Debian Linux version 9.5 operating system. The prompt under my Debian version 9.5 Linux operating system is `Russell@Russell1-PC: $`. (I have Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) configured on my personal computer). In the "Host name:" field of the WinSCP dialog box (using SFTP), I enter `Russell@Russell1-PC,` then I enter the username and password for my Debian version 9.5 Linux account, but I get the error message: "Network error. Connection to Russell1-PC refused."

What should I do differently?

Comment: Does the debian machine have a unique IP or does it share one with your windows system?  Either way I'm guessing there is a better way to transfer files than SCP considering these machines likely share a hard drive.

Comment: From your Linux machine you can use `smbclient` to transfer files from windows to your Linux.

Comment: See this tutorial - https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/winscp/. Sounds like you need to confirm that you have the correct login/password to get into the Linux system.

Comment: Since I have Windows Subsystem for Linux configured on my personal computer, this means that Microsoft Windows 10 and Debian Linux version 9.5 share the same computer ( which I am sure you all know ).  After further consideration, I am not so sure WinSCP will solve the problem ( there is no remote computer involved ).  I have tried the command "cp -f  -R -L -p  'c:/path ( Windows )' /path/to/Linux ( Debian )" from the Linux command line, but receive the error message: "cp: cannot stat 'c:/path ( Windows )' : No such file or directory."  Any suggestions?

Comment: See [How do I access the WSL Linux file system from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513597/how-do-i-access-the-wsl-linux-file-system-from-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use WinSCP neither any other network application.

From WSL you can access the Windows partition via `/mnt`, e.g. the contents of `c:\mypath` are accessible via Linux under `/mnt/c/mypath`.

So to copy a file from your Windows 10 home directory to your Linux home directory, use this command:

```
cp /mnt/c/Users/Russell/myfile.txt ~/
```

Just remember not to modify any Linux file via Windows, [as explained here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

Comment: Thank you dr01.  That is what I was looking for.  I am assuming "~/" is the Debian version 9.5 Linux root directory, and that it must be typed in as it appears?  Also, for a recursive application, I am assuming the command would be: "cp -R /mnt/c/Users/Russell/* ~/" ?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, `~/` is the current user directory. And yes, you can use recursive copy.